# db_or() in hook_query_TAG_alter?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm new to Drupal 7, but not to Drupal. I'm afraid, however, that the new database query system is a bit over my head.

I'm attempting to alter a view query using `hook_query_TAG_alter()`. In essence, I'm attempting to append an OR to the filter, saying "list nodes where the current user is either referenced in a particular_field OR is the author."

I'm attempting to append this last condition (or is the author) do this by adding a `db_or()->condition(…)` to the query, but I keep getting a fatal error:

> Call to undefined method SelectQuery::db_or() in /Volumes/...

It's driving me batshit, because I don't understand this system enough to know why this method is unavailable. Here is my implementation:

```
function sentinel_network_query_views_networks_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->db_or()->condition('node.uid', '***CURRENT_USER***', '=');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db_or()` returns a database condition instance so you need to pass it to the query as a condition. Also, you need more than one condition in `db_or()` to actually perform an or!

```
$or = db_or()
  ->condition('node.uid', '***CURRENT_USER***', '=')
  ->condition('node.nid', 'SECOND CONDITION');
$query->condition($or);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Does this actually add an or to the existing condition, or does this replace the current conditions?  It looks like it would do the latter.

Comment: `$query->condition()` adds a new condition; it doesn't replace the existing one.

Comment: So my understanding is that I can't just add an OR to the current condition, but I can leave that condition out of the view itself and add a original condition OR my new condition this way?

Comment: There could be multiple conditions attached to the query so you'd have to loop through them to see if you can identify the one you want to change, then replace it with your OR.

Answer (score 0):

[db_or()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_or/7) is a function not a method.

As example of how `db_or()` is used, you can look at the example code given for [hook_query_TAG_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7):

```
  $access_alias = $query->join('node_access', 'na', '%alias.nid = n.nid');
  $or = db_or();
  // If any grant exists for the specified user, then user has access to the node for the specified operation.
  foreach (node_access_grants($op, $query->getMetaData('account')) as $realm => $gids) {
    foreach ($gids as $gid) {
      $or->condition(db_and()
        ->condition($access_alias . '.gid', $gid)
        ->condition($access_alias . '.realm', $realm)
      );
    }
  }

  if (count($or->conditions())) {
    $query->condition($or);
  }

  $query->condition($access_alias . 'grant_' . $op, 1, '>=');
```

`$query->condition()` doesn't replace the existing condition; it adds a new condition. 
In [SelectQuery::__construct()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3a__construct/7), `SelectQuery::$where` (which contains the `DatabaseCondition` object for the query) is initialized using the following code:

```
 $this->where = new DatabaseCondition('AND');
```

This means that all the conditions added to a `SelectQuery` object will be joined to each other using the "AND" operator.